# Is there a way to get rid of this switch and make it into a smaller block of code?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have this switch in my code and it takes up a ton of space. Is there a way to make it into a smaller block of code?

```
switch(datatype)
{
    case OSMP_BYTE: // char
    {
        datatypeSize = sizeof(char);
        break;
    }
    case OSMP_INT: // int
    {
        datatypeSize = sizeof(int);
        break;
    }
    case OSMP_SHORT: // short int
    {
        datatypeSize = sizeof(short int);
        break;
    }
    case OSMP_LONG: // long int
    {
        datatypeSize = sizeof(long int);
        break;
    }
    case OSMP_UNSIGNED_CHAR: // unsigned char
    {
        datatypeSize = sizeof(unsigned char);
        break;
    }
    case OSMP_UNSIGNED: // unsigned int
    {
        datatypeSize = sizeof(unsigned int);
        break;
    }
    case OSMP_UNSIGNED_LONG: // unsigned long int
    {
        datatypeSize = sizeof(unsigned long int);
        break;
    }
    case OSMP_FLOAT: // float
    {
        datatypeSize = sizeof(float);
        break;
    }
    case OSMP_DOUBLE: // double
    {
        datatypeSize = sizeof(double);
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
}
```

My datatypes are defined like this:

```
typedef enum {
    OSMP_SHORT = 1,
    OSMP_INT,
    OSMP_LONG,
    OSMP_UNSIGNED_CHAR,
    OSMP_UNSIGNED,
    OSMP_UNSIGNED_LONG,
    OSMP_FLOAT,
    OSMP_DOUBLE,
    OSMP_BYTE
} OSMP_Datatype;
```

If there is a way to make it smaller and fit better into my code, I'd really be helped.

Comment: Sure, a look-up table. Question is how many times do you call this? Does it really matter in the end? You could minimize the code a little by having this as a function and just `return sizeof(...)` instead, avoiding all the `break` junk. Then you could one-line each definition.

Comment: You can write each `case:` of the switch on one line to save space, e.g. `case OSMP_BYTE: datatypeSize = sizeof(char); break;` -- up to you. The lookup table is another great option.

Comment: What system are you designing? What do these enum represent? Do you do any other operations with the data?

Comment: You can ditch the curly braces, and you can use [X-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) to condense the case clauses: _e.g._ `CASE(UNSIGNED_CHAR, unsigned char);` where `#define CASE(E, T) case OSMP_##E: datatypeSize = sizeof(T); break` -- however I agree with the first comment that questions just how important it is that this is compact and/or easily edited.. Because it looks like you're unlikely to be adding loads of additional types or modifying them significantly.  Usually the least-obscure code is the best code.  But just tidy it up a little, because yours is overly verbose.

Comment: I'm designing a library for operating system message passing using shared memory

Comment: [Lookup Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible approach with a lookup table as was suggested in the comments:

```
typedef enum {
    OSMP_SHORT = 0,
    OSMP_INT,
    OSMP_LONG,
    OSMP_UNSIGNED_CHAR,
    OSMP_UNSIGNED,
    OSMP_UNSIGNED_LONG,
    OSMP_FLOAT,
    OSMP_DOUBLE,
    OSMP_BYTE,
} OSMP_Datatype;

size_t OSMP_Size[] = 
{
    [OSMP_SHORT] = sizeof(short int),
    [OSMP_INT] = sizeof(int),
    [OSMP_LONG] = sizeof(long int),
    [OSMP_UNSIGNED_CHAR] = sizeof(unsigned char),
    [OSMP_UNSIGNED] =  sizeof(unsigned int),
    [OSMP_UNSIGNED_LONG] = sizeof(unsigned long int),
    [OSMP_FLOAT] = sizeof(float),
    [OSMP_DOUBLE] = sizeof(double),
    [OSMP_BYTE] = sizeof(char),
};

size_t sizeofType(OSMP_Datatype type)
{
    if((type >= 0) && (type < sizeof(OSMP_Size)/sizeof(size_t)))
        return OSMP_Size[type];
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Here it is better if the enums are continuous and start from zero, because it makes the lookup more straightforward to implement. Note that this uses designated initializers so it works only on C99 upwards. Also incompatible with C++, as pointed out by @paddy.

Also, the code might look more compact, but don't expect it to perform any better than your switch-case.

Comment: I wonder what `sizeofType(OSMP_LONG)` will return...

Comment: Oops! I missed that one while copy pasting, but to answer your question, it would return 0.

Comment: Well, I know what it would return... the point is that it's very easy to make mistakes with this type of code. As a "little" improvement I'll suggest that initializers are placed in the same order as the enum

Comment: Good spotting.  Designated array initializers are convenient in C, but it should be mentioned that they are not portable to C++ (which is sometimes desirable).  There may be some benefit also in having an assert if `sizeofType` is about to return zero in either codepath.

Comment: @4386427 Any easier than missing `case OSMP_LONG`? Or one of the breaks in a long sequence of switch-cases? Yes of course, changing the order makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Regarding a missing case statement, no it's not that much different.  One potential issue would be that it's possible to provide a negative value for the enum which would be UB in this program but not in a switch statement.

Comment: @paddy Added a note on the C++ incompatibility. And you're right again, ideally we should test for negative values as well.

Comment: Do you mean that you've explicitly considered that a negative value of `type` will automatically be cast to unsigned because of the unsigned comparison and thus underflow to test larger than the array size?  That seems sketchy to me.  Oh, you edited your comment, then edited your answer...  Now I sound like some dude shouting into the void.

Comment: @paddy ya, it's a bit unclear. Enums can be negative. So yes, better to test for it explicitly. Sorry, this comment editing feature is easy and tempting to misuse :)

Answer (score 0):

> My datatypes are defined like this:

For fun, try:

```
typedef enum {
    OSMP_SHORT = (0 << 16) | sizeof(short),
    OSMP_INT = (1 << 16) | sizeof(int),
    OSMP_LONG = (2 << 16) | sizeof(long),
    OSMP_UNSIGNED_CHAR = (3 << 16) | sizeof(unsigned char),
    OSMP_UNSIGNED = (4 << 16) | sizeof(unsigned),
    OSMP_UNSIGNED_LONG = (5 << 16) | sizeof(unsigned long),
    OSMP_FLOAT = (6 << 16) | sizeof(float),
    OSMP_DOUBLE = (7 << 16) | sizeof(double),
    OSMP_BYTE = (8 << 16) | sizeof(uint8_t),
} OSMP_Datatype;

#define OSMP_DataSizeMask 0x0000FFFF
```

..and then the code can be:

```
    datatypeSize = datatype & OSMP_DataSizeMask;
```